# Windows 7: Constant BSOD's and Laptop restarts

Tags: windows-7, bsod

This is the error that i get on restart:

---

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name: BlueScreen
  OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
  Locale ID: 16393

Additional information about the problem:
  BCCode: d1
  BCP1: 00000004
  BCP2: 00000002
  BCP3: 00000000
  BCP4: 8B19301D
  OS Version: 6_1_7600
  Service Pack: 0_0
  Product: 256_1

Files that help describe the problem:
  C:\Windows\Minidump\032610-17487-01.dmp
  C:\Users\ForceOne\AppData\Local\Temp\WER-30591-0.sysdata.xml

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

---

The dump files are [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/368151218/dump_files.rar) if anyone wants them, anyone knows the solution to this?

***Extra Info: I have a Dell Inspiron 1525 with Windows 7***

Comment: Had you installed any new apps when the problem started? A quick google shows this BSOD is common after getting a trojan.

Comment: no new apps xcept that i downloaded wordpress on my local server and a few themesand plugins, that's all